# Getting error, while adding share point site to the existing projects (Work item Color error) in TFS 2015.3

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

We are getting error, while adding share point portals (using **TFPT** command) to some of the existing projects in TFS 2015.3.

to be clear, we have a project called ABC and it has Agile process template (properly upgraded from TFS 2013.4 to TFS 2015.3). while trying to share point poral, it throwing below error,
**Event Description: TF30162: Task "ProcessConfiguration" from Group "WorkItemTracking" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: The following element contains an error: WorkItemColor. TF401092: This element defines the color for the work item types for this team project. A 'WorkItemColor' element has the following value for the 'name' attribute: 'Product Backlog Item'. A WorkItemColor element must refer to an existing work item type in the team project. Modify the name attribute to an existing work item type, or remove the element.**

ABC project does not have any product backlog work item (surprised), could you please advise us ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the **ProcessConfiguration** file of ABC team project, it may define a color for your Product Backlog Item. You need to export this file and remove the color for PBI because your team project doesn't have this workitem type.

1. Export the ProcessConfiguration file:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration
2. Remove/delete this: `<WorkItemColor primary="xxxxxxxx" secondary="xxxxxxxx" name="Product Backlog Item" />`
3. Save and import your ProcessConfiguration file.

Comment: I dint see "<WorkItemColor primary="xxxxxxxx" secondary="xxxxxxxx" name="Product Backlog Item" />" in the process config file to delete/remove this information. FYI, we properly upgraded all team projects to latest version of TFS .

Comment: @Sam Did  you custom the Agile template and use it for this team project? And did you do the [Configure Features](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) after upgrading?

Comment: Yes I did configure Features after upgrade